# Trying to improve Entity Framework performance when querying children of related collections, and their children

Tags: performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to determine if it's my usage of Entity Framework, or if I just can't get the performance I desire using EF.

I have a structure where "Transactions" have a collection (usually 1-5 items) of "Actions" which in turn have a collection of "Responses" (usually 2-6 items). In most cases, I care about Transactions where ***any*** of the Actions meet the specific search criteria, with the most recent "Response" (or lack thereof) determining the status, which is what we're querying based upon.

So, most of my queries (IQueryable, built dynamically) look something like:

```
Context.Transactions.AsNoTracking().Where(w => w.Actions.Any(action => action.Responses.OrderByDescending(o => o.Id).FirstOrDefault().Type == [Search Type]) || **(1-5 similar filters)**)
```

I'm executing the query 3 times... 1) get the total result count, 2) get distinct values of a few fields for the entire result set to populate some search criteria in the UI, and 3) to grab the full view model of 25-100 results to display. **Maybe there's a better way to do this?**

I tried querying against the "Transaction" table directly (as above) and alternatively projecting to an intermediate model that does my ordering and finds the "last response type" before apply the various filters. That looks something like:

```
Context.Transactions.AsNoTracking().ToSummaryModel().Where(w => w.Any(action => action.LastResponseType == [search type] || ...)
```

... where the "ToSummaryModel" projects a condensed version of Actions with the **latest** Response type from the Responses sub-collection.

In the most frequent use cases, we'll be looking at about 8,000-12,000 Transaction records, with occasional queries of 100,000+.

In expected use cases, the results are taking 15-20 seconds to execute, with outlier cases taking a minute+. Can I approach anything differently to potentially cut execution down to 25-30% (or better) of current?

Comment: What happens in `ToSummaryModel()`?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the whole query (which may be impractical) it will be hard to narrow down an exact cause, but I would suspect a 20 second execution time for a structure / data volume like that, let alone a minute+ is certainly unreasonable.  A few things to check:

When it comes to optional filters, you can either handle the optional nature (i.e. null check) inside the expression, or outside the expression with an 'if(filter != null)`. In almost all cases it is better for performance to perform the null check in code and only append supplied filters rather than encoding the checks into the expressions.

Finding "latest" children is bound to be expensive.  When considering computed values like this, I would consider opting for a database View to formulate the "search" aspect of locating these transactions where-by once a transaction is selected, loading that singular transaction and related entities from the respective tables rather than searching based on the table relationships. Alternatively this may be a case to justify denormalizing the latest action reference on the transaction.

However, prior to that it can help to record any/all SQL queries with a profiler on the database to build a picture of what EF is doing to get your data. Executing those queries with an execution plan (SQL Server) could reveal missing indexes that could make a big difference. Looking at the queries being run might also reveal additional issues such as lazy-loads creeping in after one or more of the queries has run. Digging further would require seeing the exact linq expressions being built because each situation is unique when it comes to performance issues.

Comment: Thanks, Steve. I am doing the optional filters in code. I'll try the view option, that's a good idea. I think I've done that before, but it's been a long time and it slipped my mind. Thanks for the feedback/ideas, sorry I didn't have more code, but it's complex enough and proprietary enough that it's challenging to share without missing stuff.